# Creat REST Api Using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Restful Api for following methods to run jenkins jobs to run on saucelabs. I wanna queue jobs using restful API. I am using Django Restful Framework.

1. CreateMethod :
        Accepts two fileds: ProjectName and URL
        and returns a Token ID.
2. VerifyStatus:
        Accepts Token ID and returns three fields. TokenID, running:True/False and 
        no_of_jobs: integervalue (0 if Not specified)
3. relseaseMethod:
       Accepts release token call and returns true if success.

I am new to Restful API with, I am trying to run Jenkins job on sauce lab and queue them using a restful api on python Djano restframework. Guide me through.

**Views.py**

```
class RegisterTestMethodView(APIView):
authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  #No access (not even read if not authorized)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = RegisterTestMethodSerializers(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'tokenid':serializer.data['id']}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CheckStatusView(APIView):


def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Jobs.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Jobs.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    snippet = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = RegisterTestMethodSerializers(snippet)
    return Response({"tokenid":serializer.data["id"], "Runtestnow" : False, "VMcount" : 0 })


class ReleaseTokenView(APIView):

def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Jobs.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Jobs.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    snippet = self.get_object(pk)
    snippet.delete()
    return Response(data={'Deleted':True}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Serailizers.py

```
rom rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Jobs
from random import random



RegisterTestMethodSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = ('id','name','url')
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Jobs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import (RegisterTestMethodView,
                    RegisterTestMethodViewDetail,
                    CheckStatusView,
                    ReleaseTokenView
                    )
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView



urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('registertestmethod/',RegisterTestMethodView.as_view()),
    path('registertestmethod/<int:pk>/', 
    RegisterTestMethodViewDetail.as_view()),
    path('checkstatus/<int:pk>', CheckStatusView.as_view()),
    path('releasetoken/<int:pk>', ReleaseTokenView.as_view()),
]
```

I have addded my Code here. I have other classes and function in my project as well.I tried to delete all of those. You might see extra import as a result of that. My code does following things.

`POST --> http://localhost:8000/registertestmethod/`

```
{

    "name": "Name",
    "url": "https://www.google.com"
}
```

returns

```
{
    "tokenid": 32 #unique token ID return 
}
```

This **tokenid** should be long I am using id as of now.

`GET --> http://localhost:8000/checkstatus/32`

is returning

```
{
    "tokenid": 32, #unique tokenid refering to register info
    "Runtestnow": false, #if job is running
    "VMcount": 0 # number of VM used in sauce lab by the Jobs
}
```

`DELETE --> http://localhost:8000/releasetoken/32` #should delete the jobs after done.
 is deleting  and returning

```
{
    "Deleted": true
}
```

I want it to be dynamic and store info in database. Token should return everything on checkstatus.

Comment: What is your question? What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: I wanna create an API which we can use as queue handler for jenking job run on sauce labs VMs. We have multiple tests we have to run on sauce lab but limited VMs. We wanna give fixed number of Jenkins jobs to run on Sauce lab using an API where we give three api Method Registertestmethod, checkstatus and releasetoken after the job is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ModelViewSet approach for this, this here is a very simple example for an API endpoint.

views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from api.serializers import SaucelabsSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response


class SaucelabModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SaucelabSerializer
    queryset = Sauselab.objects.all() 
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'options', 'post']

    def create(self, request):
        pnam = request.data.get('project_name', None)
        url = request.data.get('url', None)
        if pnam and url:
            # do something here
            return Response({'success': 'Your success message'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Your error message"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializer import ModelSerializer
from appname.models import Saucelab

class SaucelabSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Saucelab
        fields = '__all__'
```

appname/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Saucelab(models.Model)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from api import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('your-endpoint-name', views.SaucelabModelViewSet, basename='your-url-name')

urlpatterns = []

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

This is a very basic example, where you create a model called `saucelab` which has the two fields you require, ie.`project_name` and `url`.

We create a app called `api` with two files inside it that aren't auto generated, `serializers.py` and `urls.py`. We create the most basic model serializer and ask it to serialize all fields of model `Saucelab`. Then we create a simple `modelviewset` which out of the box gives you a `CRUD` functionality. You can override the `create` method if you need to run some specific conditions otherwise dont override any methods and just make request to the endpoint with appropriate HTTP methods.

Here are a few links you can read

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

To generate a random token

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
print(get_random_string(length=25))
```

output

```
u'rRXVe68NO7m3mHoBS488KdHaqQPD6Ofv'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Sahil, I was able to create an api as you mentioned. I have one more question. I wanna return a token which is unique when I am registering the registerMethod. Something like Token and use that token on checkstatus method to get other information (returns : token id(same token id) runningstatus:Ture or False and  vmcount)

Comment: To generate a token you can use Django's inbuilt util called `crypto`. I have edited my answer to reflect the same, please check.

Comment: Also if this answered your original question can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks Sahil, I am new to Stack Overflow and couldn't explain everything I have added my code and little description as well. Could you please take a look and let me know if I am doing it right.

Comment: No worries @david I have been bombarded with down votes and often banned to ask any questions, when I was new as well. I suppose it's a path of pain everyone has to go through, don't let it discourage you, this community is pretty awesome. Stick around!